# Real-time notification not able to implement

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, laravel-5.6

I am trying to implement real time notification in laravel5.6 with reactjs. My requirement is , implement this via socket.io. I have followed laravel documentation broadcasting section. In console I got the socket calling details. It's calling to port 6001.

1. But CORS warning I am getting.
2. How can show the details of notification in front-end bell icon

Please help me to solve this issues.

Thanks advance

Comment: Hi Sumesh. Can you show an example of the CORS warning you get, and the client code that is connecting to the socket?

Comment: I have installed redis server. Now the cors error gone. Now there is no error, but nothing listening. Broadcast event success fully worked. photo artisan serve is running, laravel echo is running and redis is running

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51

Comment: I got proper fix for my requirements from above url